# CosmosDB NoSQL API query - Distinct Count

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql-aggregation

I am trying to create a query to count the total orders that have quote(s) of different status (i.e., ACTIVE and VOID); I'd like to get the distinct count, which means if there are two Quote items with "VOID" status in the Quote list of an order item, the expected count value of order items with VOID quote status should be 1 rather than 2.

Below is a simplification version of my data model.

```
Model/Container: order
Columns/Components:
String orderId;
String orderStatus;
LocalDateTime dateCreatedStamp;
LocalDateTime dateModifiedStamp;
List<Quote> quotes;
```

For the Quote object, it has the following fields:

```
String quoteId;
String quoteStatus; //ACTIVE and VOID
LocalDatetime quoteDateCreatedStamp;
LocalDatetime quoteDateModifiedStamp;
```

I wrote the query below, but the count it returns is not distinct. For example, if there are two Quote items with "VOID" status in the Quote list of an order item, the count value for VOID status would be 2 rather than 1, which is different from the requirement/expectation stated above.

```
SELECT q.quoteStatus, COUNT(or)
FROM order or
JOIN q IN or.quotes
WHERE q.quoteStatus IN ("ACTIVE", "VOID")
GROUP BY q.quoteStatus
```

Besides, I also checked the official documentations below related to CosmosDB queries:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/samples-java-spring-data
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/keywords
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/group-by](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Hi Roar, thank you for pointing it out, and sorry about the confusion! I have updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

By using a `JOIN` you flatten the elements of the quotes sequence into separate items. Instead you should use the array functions, which will let you operations without flattening the result.

```sql
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1)
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.quotes, { 'quoteStatus': 'VOID' }, true)
```

The above searches in the array if any of the quotes has the status `VOID`. That'll allow you to filter without the `JOIN` and aggregate on the order instead of quote statuses.

---

For more complex queries like filtering on a range you can try the following:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM c
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM q IN c.quotes WHERE q.quoteDate > '2020-01-01') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM q IN c.quotes WHERE q.quoteStatus IN ('VOID', 'ACTIVE'))
```

Comment: Many thanks! I think the above works perfect if we only want to do the de-dup count for shipment items that have "VOID" status quote, but what if we want to output to show the count by different status? And what if we want to add further conditions, say quoteLastModified within a certain time range?

Comment: For multiple statuses you could just add an `AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(...)`. For ranges (or any other filter that doesn't check on exact values) you'll have to create a more complex sql statement. I've added an example in the answer.